activation of network
when connected to wifi after some time the message is displaying "Activation of network connection failed" and wifi do not show my wifi ssid until restarts. The same repeats when try to connect.
i tried in commandline. the following error occured.
Error: Connection activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
rt3290 driver for linux is required for my laptop.
belkin patch downloaded on somebody's advise and installed by force.
but did not work.
i think instead of working on such issues the alternately usb ethernet can be better as it is working.
Really it is taking all my time with no answer.
and my objective has taken side track and this problem became the aim.

escription: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
The above is the installed version. newly installed along with win 10 to learn ubuntu and start to use it as it may be more secured than windows.

Please don't add details as comments, edit your question instead.

As you said edited and updated my question with latest status after my concerted efforts.

The question does not show the added info so something is wrong.

Dear friends , I could resolve the problem. vi  /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

Dear friends , I could resolve my problem. vi  /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and changed the 3 to 2. power saving off in case of wifi driver. to see the status use iwconfig. my experience is that i verified the syslog  and searched for the resolution in the stack exchange for that errors instead of referring the tag WIFI CONNECTION FAILURE.

but it has again disconnected automatically. after that i have set ntp set to zero after seeing the error in syslog. then started working now. but it may be uncertain. nobody could answer this   question.  it seems question is not interested.
